# How to approach the problems in the Hoffman Kunze book?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, advice

I’m considering the idea to solve the entire set of problems contained in the Hoffman-Kunze text. The standard results of Linear Algebra are known to me.

1. I don’t have much time to read the textual materials. Is there any harm if I skip reading text and solve only the problems?
2. Would, in your opinion, selecting problems arbitrarily from any part of the text to solve be a good idea?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're mathematically mature enough to skip reading a text and jump to solving problem, why not pursue something more challenging? For example, reading a research article and then presenting it to a group of students interested in similar areas?

Comment: I find the circumstances here a bit odd. How do you not have enough time to read the text but think you will have sufficient time to do all the problems. What do you think "standard results" in linear algebra are, e.g., do you know about dual spaces? And of course the title of this post ("How to read a text") is completely orthogonal to your intentions, which is *not* to read the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) No. There is no harm in attempting problems. If you solve them, that's fine. If you get stuck, you can read the text to get more background. (2) Yes. Pick any problem you like, though you may find that you make better progress by doing the earlier problems first.